# Joomla 3.3 unable to login as administrator

Tags: joomla

I've actually answered this question, but thought I'd put it up here to save anyone else the wasted hours since upgrading to 3.3.

I was able to login at the front-end, so knew the password was working. However, it just returned to the login screen without error in /administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the configuration.php file in the root directory and make sure that the cookie domain is either has www. prefixed or not depending on your host's preference.